# How to allow/disallow create and delete on One2Many field tree?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

I have a One2Many field called `lines`. I display the field as a tree in a form view like this.

```
<field name="lines">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        <field 
         ... doesn't matter ...
        />
    </tree>
</field>
```

The field is now editable but I would like to change it so that it will allow to create/delete the records within the tree by some conditions.

I tried `create="0" delete="0"` in the tree but it only works for `"0"` and `"1"`. I can't seem to find the way to put a condition in there.

How to overcome such challenge? The conditions can just be depending on the parent's state -- simple conditions.

Comment: Just add `attrs` with `readonly` in your field definition of `lines`. For example `<field name="lines" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done'])]}" />`. Care about the domain, because the fields belong to the parent model.

Comment: @CZoellner You can put the comment as an answer. It solves the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `attrs` on the field itself, because besides the often used `invisible` attribute you also can use `readonly`and `required`.

Using `readonly` with a domain on the field will lead to other usable fields. Because the field `lines` is a x2many relation (child) so the fields of the parent are usable.

Because i don't know the models here, let's assume we have the known one2many relation `sale.order` and `sale.order.line` and we want the lines to get readonly when the `state` field has either the value `sale` or `done`.

```xml
<field name="order_line" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done'])]}">
    <tree>...</tree>
</field>
```